# Using (relative) paths to shortcut in include statements in C++

Tags: c++, header-files, relative-path, shortcut

I started coding in C++ few days ago. I am using windows as my OS for writing code. I have been keeping all of my "well-written" codes in a single location. Now, I am working on a project that requires the use of those codes. So, I planned to include those files that I require as header files in my project. However, to make my project "self-contained", I created shortcuts of those folders that I require and kept them in the source folder of my new project and decided to use relative paths to the shortcuts in the "`include`" statements in my project.

However, I am getting an error. Is there any way to use relative (or, in general, absolute) paths to shortcuts in the `include` statements of C++ in windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It really depends on *how* you include the header files.

If you include with double-quotes, like e.g.

```
#include "some_header_file.h"
```

Then the relative path is from the current files location.

If you include using angle-brackets, like e.g.

```
#include <some_header_file.h>
```

Then the relative path is based on the system include paths.

You can always add a path to the system include path. How to do it depend on your environment and compiler. If you're using Visual Studio you go into the project properties dialog, and in the "C/C++" / "General" tab there is a field called "Additional Include Directories" where you can add directories. (This is for VS 2015, might be a little different on other versions.)

---

Regarding double quotes inclusion. Lets say your project hierarchy looks like this (on *disk*!):

```
Project
|-- Include
|-- Source
|   `-- MoreSource
`-- Other
```

In `Project/Source` you have your source files, and if one of them want to include a header file from `Project/Include`, then it will look something like

```
#include "../Include/header.h"
```

Now if you have a source file in `Project/Source/MoreSource` that want to include the same header file it will be

```
#include "../../Include/header.h"
```

It could be useful to add the `Project/Include` directory to the system header search path. You can still use double-quotes to include the files, since if they are not found then the preprocessor will search the system paths as well, but you don't need the "full" relative path. If you add `Project/Include` to the system header path, you could write just

```
#include "header.h"
```

Or

```
#include <header.h>
```

Be careful though, if you have a header file with the same name as an actual system header file you might have some trouble.

Comment: Hi, I am actually using double quotes. However, the preprocessor replies that it cannot find the (shortcut) folder. If I copy my original folder to the location of my source code, it works fine. However, to avoid redundancy, I do not want that

Comment: @Python_user Without knowing your exact disk directory structure it's really impossible to give you a definitive answer, But I updated my answer with an example that hopefully helps you.

Comment: I have my "original" files in some location. I do not want to copy those files into my new project to avoid redundancy. So, I created shortcuts to them, copied those shortcuts into my project and tried to include the relative path to the shortcuts in my code. That's where I am getting an error.

Comment: However, if I include the relative path to my original source code, it works fine. But, I dont want that since I want to make my project "self-contained".

Comment: @Python_user Then I *really* recommend you add the original path to your project settings.

Comment: Thanks, in the worst case I will be doing that. But is there any way to make them work with shortcuts (thats what my doubt is!) since I want make my project "self-contained" (in some sense)?

Comment: Or rather. I want to make my project "appear" self-contained.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, is the inconsistency between `include` and `Include` in your example intentional? I think it is not, but I cannot correct only two characters.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Just a typo. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

From https://superuser.com/questions/253935/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-link-and-shortcut

You can't include folder shortcut since it's a file, not a folder.

You can read the guide to [create symbolic link on windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for you to refer to the conversation in the answer given by @Some programmer dude? (since it would avoid restating my query again)