# How to include a header file from a shared library?

Tags: c++, include

### What is the current state?

My folder structure:

```
--home
   |---an_awesome_lib
   |    |---Core
   |         |---src
   |         |    |---header_of_lib.h
   |         |
   |         |---build
   |              |---libawesome.so
   |
   |---framework
        |---project
              |---my_program_header.h
```

In my_program_header.h I have the following line:

`#include <an_awesome_lib/Core/src/header_of_lib.h>`

I tell g++:

`-I</home/an_awesome_lib/Core/src/header_of_ib.h> -lawesome -L/home/an_awesome_lib/build`

### Problem Description

When I write `#include<home/an_awesome_lib/Core/src/header_of_lib.h>` the compiler does not throw an error. But I do not want to do it. I want sth. like `#include <an_awesome_lib/Core/src/header_of_lib.h>` This is a simple problem and it has been asked very often. However I do not see the relationship between the paths given to g++ and the path in #include in the code.

### Where I found some information:

I read there but there was no complete explanation which puts this all together.

[What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

[How do I include a path to libraries in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Using (relative) paths to shortcut in include statements in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714365/using-relative-paths-to-shortcut-in-include-statements-in-c)

---

### What I want

I hope you have a general explanation which puts this in a context. The following bullet points are just some suggestions to make it more clear what I would like to know.

- When do I need to tell the whole path?
- When is a relative path sufficient?
- How does the path in the header file relate to the path given to g++? Are they in a relationship?
- Are there multiple solutions, one which restricts it a bit more, one which is more open?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I tell #include the complete path it works"? Do you mean your compiler does not throw any error? What path are you using in your g++ command?

Comment: You can do `-I/home` and then write `#include <an_awesome_lib/.../header_of_lib.h>`. But it would be better to create a directory `include/an_awesome_lib` inside `an_awesome_lib`, and then use `-I/home/an_awesome_lib/include`. Take a look at Boost directory structure, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-I` specifies an include **directory**, not a file. GCC documentation [reads](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation):

> `-I dir`
>
> ...
>
> Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files during preprocessing.

[and](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html):

> Both user and system header files are included using the preprocessing directive `#include`. It has two variants:
>
> `#include <file>`
>
> This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the `-I` option.
>
> ...

---

If you want to be able to write

```
#include <an_awesome_lib/Core/src/header_of_lib.h>
```

then you should specify `/home` as an include directory:

```
-I/home
```

However, including the whole `home` directory is not a good idea. I suggest you change the directory structure of your awesome library. For example, you could mimic Boost and create `an_awesome_lib` directory inside `an_awesome_lib`:

```
an_awesome_lib
  |--- an_awesome_lib
```

and then use `-I/home/an_awesome_lib`.

Or you can create `include/an_awesome_lib` inside `an_awesome_lib`:

```
an_awesome_lib
  |--- include
         |--- an_awesome_lib
```

and then use `-I/home/an_awesome_lib/include`.